# Fide Ratings Commercial Use

Tags: fide, online-chess, elo

Can I use fide ratings data for commercial use? I am specifically asking about the [ratings list](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) fide publishes every month. Also wondering if I scrape individual player-opponent statistics from fide website, can I use that for commercial use?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I use fide ratings data for commercial use?

The [FIDE ratings download page](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) has no restrictions on what you may use the data for, so, yes you may use the data for any legal purpose.

There are commercial organisations which already do exactly that. As an arbiter I purchased my copy of Swiss Manager pairing software several years ago. Every time I run competition I click on the option to get the latest FIDE ratings and the program goes away, downloads the latest rating file from the FIDE site and processes that to extract the data it needs.

For an example of an organisation which *does* place restrictions on what its downloaded data may be used for check out the [Google Ngram data download page](https://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv3.html). There it says:

> Usage: This compilation is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

This Creative Commons License allows you to use the data for any purpose whatsoever, including commercial, provided you attribute the original data to the owner and pass on the license to anybody who uses your data.

Comment: Thank you Brian! This is very helpful